# Hooking up a custom stripe button to back-end

Tags: html, laravel, stripe-payments

Let's suppose I have a custom implementation of stripe, such as this.

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>

<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh',
  image: '/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
  locale: 'auto',
  token: function(token) {
    // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
    // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
  }
});

$('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
  // Open Checkout with further options:
  handler.open({
    name: 'Stripe.com',
    description: '2 widgets',
zipCode: true,
    amount: 2000
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation:
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});
</script>
```

I have a function in the back-end which is accessed via the route '/charge' and is of PUT type. This function takes care of the charge, and was written in PHP (laravel).

I used to have the simple implementation that submitted a form to the /charge route like this.

```
  <form action="/charge" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Stripe.com"
    data-description="2 widgets"
    data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto"
data-zip-code=&quot;true&quot;>
  </script>
  </form>
```

I am trying to find a way to send the more complex custom way to the /charge method. I am not too sure if I am thinking about this the correct way.

The reason I switched to the more complex way, was so I could customize the blue stripe 'pay with card' button with CSS to look different.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to submit the token as a POST parameter to your URL. Typically, this is done by submitting a form. The form might already exist, or you can create it dynamically. For example:

```
token: function(token) {
  // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
  // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.setAttribute('method', "post");
  form.setAttribute('action', "/charge");

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute('type', "hidden");
  input.setAttribute('name', "stripeToken");
  input.setAttribute('value', token.id);

  form.appendChild(input);
  form.submit();
}
```

When the callback `token` is executed, it dynamically creates a form with `/charge` as its `action` attribute, adds the token ID as an hidden input, and submits the form.